# mysql split search string by space and push into query

Tags: php, mysql

The search query is:

"product1 prod2 prod4"

I need to make the mysql

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tableprod 
  WHERE (prod LIKE '%product1%' 
         AND prod LIKE '%prod2%' 
         AND prod LIKE '%prod4%')
```

using the mysql_real_escape_string for the input query...

Answer (score 8):

Simple string manipulation:

```
$terms = explode(' ', $search);

$bits = array();
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $bits[] = "prod LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($term)."%'";
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM tableprod WHERE (".implode(' AND ', $bits).")";
```

Comment: just what i was looking from and is here since 6 years

Answer (score 1):

If you can meet the constraints, you migh be better off just using a [FULLTEXT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) index which would save you the trouble of having to split the string, plus you'd get the bonus of being able to use basic boolean operators for the search (and/or/not)

Answer (score 1):

without a loop(i've always tried to avoid loops):

```
$str = "product1 prod2 prod4";
$sql = "select * from tableprod where (prod like '%" . str_replace( ' ', '%\' AND prod LIKE \'%', $str ) . '%\')';
```

if it's possible you will have more than one space inbetween items use preg_replace

Comment: Whats wrong with loops? @tim-fountain solution is clearer to read and alter.