# PHP MySQL WHERE column-value is in $_POST

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to get all the rows which contain a particular text. However, when I execute the query, no rows are returned. I'm retrieving the text from a post request which looks like this "Krachttraining,Spinning" (= 2 values). I think my code fails on the following part (if I leave this out, the query returns some rows): `AND CONCAT('%', sport.name, '%') LIKE $sports`.

FYI. I know you can perform SQL injection on this, this will be fixed later.

```
<?php
$servername = "SECRET";
$username = "SECRET";
$dbpassword = "SECRET";
$dbname = "SECRET";

$lat = $_POST['lat'];
$lng = $_POST['lng'];
$sports = $_POST['sports'];

echo $sports; //Echo's: Krachttraining,Spinning.

// Create connection.
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $dbpassword, $dbname);

// Check connection.
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT gym.id FROM gym, sport, gym_sport WHERE lat BETWEEN '$lat'-1 AND '$lat'+1 AND lng BETWEEN '$lng'-1 AND '$lng'+1 AND gym.id = gym_sport.gym_id AND sport.id = gym_sport.sport_id AND CONCAT('%', sport.name, '%') LIKE $sports";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$output = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row.
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id = $row["id"];
        array_push($output, $gym);
    }

    //Brackets because of GSON's parser.
    echo "[" . json_encode($output) . "]";

}

$conn->close();
?>
```

EDIT: Changed SQL statement to:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM gym, sport, gym_sport WHERE lat BETWEEN '$lat'-1 AND '$lat'+1 AND lng BETWEEN '$lng'-1 AND '$lng'+1 AND gym.id = gym_sport.gym_id AND sport.id = gym_sport.sport_id AND sport.name LIKE '%".$sports."%'";
```

Still getting 0 rows returned.

EDIT 2: I ran the following code in my phpMyAdmin environment, and it returned 0 rows.

`Select * FROM sport WHERE name LIKE '%Krachttraining,Spinning%';`

However when I'm running the following code, it returns 1 row:

```
Select * FROM sport WHERE name LIKE '%Krachttraining%';
```

I don't really get it what I'm doing wrong, any thoughts?

Comment: `LIKE $sports` is that a string?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes it's a string

Comment: wrap it in quotes then. checking for errors on the query would have told you about it

Comment: You're treating Strings $lat as Integers in your query. That might be the problem.

Comment: *"EDIT: Instead of downvoting my question, please eloborate what's wrong with it."* - wasn't mine but your question stands to get closed based on string literals not quoted. Edit: and it was. Btw; that should have been a comment, rather than in the answer.

Comment: your thinking goes in the wrong direction us it like `" ... LIKE '%".$sports."%'"`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Alright, but I've changed that and it still isn't working, I'll edit my question.

Comment: don't overwrite your original post though; place it as an edit and remove this *"EDIT: Instead of downvoting my question, please eloborate what's wrong with it."* while you're at it.

Comment: you're not using this `$gym` anywhere. You may have meant to use `$id` and error reporting would have helped you here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- See my 2nd edit, it makes clear that there is a problem with multiple values in the LIKE clause. I don't know how to solve it though.

Comment: use `OR`'s then rather than `AND` - echo your query out and you'll see what's going in (or not). and my comment above there about `$gym`.

Comment: I'm running the code from "Edit 2" in my phpMyAdmin environment. So there's no PHP anymore. The problem is something in the LIKE statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use the `IN` statement.
This will check if any word in the array matches. 
For instance:
`Select * FROM sport WHERE name IN ('Spinning', 'Krachttraining');` 
Will return every row which has the name Spinning or Krachttraining.

Comment: I managed to solve it like this. I added the parameters by looping through them and adding them to the SQL statement. After that I executed the SQL and got the rows back which I wanted! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

```
SELECT .FROM...WHERE AND sport.name LIKE '%".$sports."%'";
```

> After question editing

After **you changed the question**, I suggest to take a look at this answer to better understand what you should to do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3902567/1076753

Anyway I think that you have to learn a bit about the like command: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-like/

Comment: Test it using only: `Select * FROM sport WHERE name LIKE '%".$sports."%'";` If it works, must be some other parameter in your query that fails.

Comment: You're asking something new now :/

Comment: **I gave you the operator to work**, if you need someone that finish the job for you, I think that you can call some freelance ;)

Comment: Except for the fact that your answer did not work. I am still solving this right now. No need to make such comments to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

Change the sql to :

```
$sql = "SELECT gym.id FROM gym, sport, gym_sport WHERE lat BETWEEN '$lat'-1 AND '$lat'+1 AND lng BETWEEN '$lng'-1 AND '$lng'+1 AND gym.id = gym_sport.gym_id AND sport.id = gym_sport.sport_id AND sport.name LIKE '%".$sports%."'";
```

Comment: I'm receiving the following error: br /><b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '.' in <b>PHPFILE</b> on line <b>19</b><br /

Comment: Sorry use this $sql = "SELECT gym.id FROM gym, sport, gym_sport WHERE lat BETWEEN '$lat'-1 AND '$lat'+1 AND lng BETWEEN '$lng'-1 AND '$lng'+1 AND gym.id = gym_sport.gym_id AND sport.id = gym_sport.sport_id AND sport.name LIKE '%".$sports."%'";

Comment: 0 rows returned.

Comment: this answer needs to be edited in order to reflect the right syntax. As it stands, `LIKE '%".$sports%."'` isn't correct. The right syntax was only mentioned in a comment.